# How to implement a test bench file for a 8x1 Multiplexer with 32-bit line width?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm writing a VHDL code to model an 8x1 multiplexer where each input has 32-bit width. So I created an array to model the MUX but now I'm stuck with the Test Bench, it's gotten so complicated. Here is my original file (I'm sure it has so many redundancies) How can I actually make the test bench to recognize my array (R_in) from the component's file and then how will I stimulate it?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY mux8_1 IS
   PORT(Rs  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
    in0,in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7 :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    R_out   :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
       );
END mux8_1;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF mux8_1 IS

type t_array_mux is array (0 to 7) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
signal R_in:t_array_mux;

BEGIN

R_in(0) <= in0;
R_in(1) <= in1;
R_in(2) <= in2;
R_in(3) <= in3;
R_in(4) <= in4;
R_in(5) <= in5;
R_in(6) <= in6;
R_in(7) <= in7;


process(R_in, Rs)
BEGIN

CASE Rs IS

WHEN "000"=>R_out<=R_in(0);
WHEN "001"=>R_out<=R_in(1);
WHEN "010"=>R_out<=R_in(2);
WHEN "011"=>R_out<=R_in(3);
WHEN "100"=>R_out<=R_in(4);
WHEN "101"=>R_out<=R_in(5);
WHEN "110"=>R_out<=R_in(6);
WHEN "111"=>R_out<=R_in(7);
WHEN OTHERS=>R_out<= (others => '0');

END CASE;
END process;
END behaviour;
```

And here is my "in progress" test bench file. Just ignore the "stimulus process" part I know it's wrong I just couldn't figure out how to write it for a 32-bit signal.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY mux8_1_TB IS
END mux8_1_TB;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF mux8_1_TB IS

COMPONENT mux8_1
   PORT(Rs  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
    in0,in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7 :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    R_out   :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
       );
END COMPONENT;

type t_array_mux is array (0 to 7) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

--Inputs
signal R_in:t_array_mux:=(others=>'0');
signal in0,in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7 :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0):=(others=>'0');
signal Rs  :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0):=(others=>'0');

--Outputs
signal R_out:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test + connect the ports to my signal
BEGIN

R_in(0) <= in0;
R_in(1) <= in1;
R_in(2) <= in2;
R_in(3) <= in3;
R_in(4) <= in4;
R_in(5) <= in5;
R_in(6) <= in6;
R_in(7) <= in7;

uut: mux8_1 PORT MAP(
    Rs=>Rs,
    R_in=>R_in,
    R_out=>R_out
       );

-- Stimulus process (where the values -> inputs are set) 

PROCESS
begin

R_in<="01010101";
    wait for 10 ns;
Rs<="001";
    wait for 10 ns;
Rs<="010";
    wait for 20 ns;
Rs<="011";
    wait for 30 ns;
Rs<="100";
    wait for 40 ns;
Rs<="101";
    wait for 50 ns;
Rs<="110";
    wait for 60 ns;
Rs<="111";
    wait for 70 ns;

END PROCESS;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `uut` port map so instead of `R_in`, it has individual `in0 - in7` ports to match your `mux8_1` component definition. Then, map `in0 - in7` testbench signals directly to these ports:

```
 uut: mux8_1 port map(
     ...
     in0 => in0,
     in1 => in1,
     ...
     );
```

Or if you want to keep the `R_in` signal, port map like this:

```
uut: mux8_1 port map(
         ...
         in0 => R_in(0),
         in1 => R_in(1),
         ...
         );
```

This assignment to `R_in` in your testbench is *incorrect:*

```
R_in<="01010101";
```

`R_in` is defined as a `t_array_mux` type, so it can't be assigned a bit vector value. It has to be assigned to an *array* of 32-bit `std_logic_vector`. That line should really be removed altogether, as you're already making assignments to `R_in` in another location outside of the process. Multiple assignments will cause signal contention.

You're initializing `R_in` in your testbench like this:

```
signal R_in:t_array_mux:=(others=>'0');
```

The `others` keyword as you've used it will only work on an individual `std_logic_vector`. You need to nest `others` for your array of `std_logic_vector`:

```
signal R_in:t_array_mux:=(others=>(others=>'0'));
```

You'll want to assign values to your 32-bit `in0 - in7` signals so you can see the output of your mux change in the sim. They can be assigned outside the stimulus process. You can assign them using hex-notation (x preceding "") or just binary:

```
in0 <= x"12345678"; --hex
```

or

```
in0 <= "00010010001101000101011001111000"; --binary
```

Your stimulus process looks fine. As you change `Rs`, you would expect to see the different input values on `R_out`. You could add a single `wait;` at the end of the process, or the process will keep repeating until the end of sim.

**Component ports with user-defined types**

Alternatively, you could `port map` your `R_in` testbench signal directly to a `R_in` port on your component as you've done, but it would take a bit more work. Your `mux8_1` component definition does not have an `R_in` port. You can add a `t_array_mux` type port named `R_in`, if you define the `t_array_mux` type in a [package](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-package.html) which you then include in your component and testbench files

```
library work;
use work.your_package_name.all;
```

in addition to `library IEEE`, etc. Then you can use the `t_array_mux` type in your component port definition:

```
ENTITY mux8_1 IS
  PORT(Rs    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
       R_in  : IN T_ARRAY_MUX; --User-defined port type
       R_out : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
       );
END mux8_1;
```

This will allow you to do the port mapping of your `uut` the way you currently have it. You'll have to add the package to the project or compile list in whatever tool you're using.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain in much detail, I've managed to change the test bench according to your suggestions (removing R_in all together+ array structure and specifying only in0-in7 as I see it won't be necessary to complicate things further in the test bench) and now it works. As for "specifying components ports with user-defined types" I will try to do it that way further down the road surely. So, I'd appreciate it a lot thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using a testbench, you can test the correctness/output behavior of your module by giving a sequence of input signals and then comparing the output signals with the expected output.

- Firstly, `R_in` is unknown to your testbench file, as it was an **internal signal** of your module. So, providing values to that signal doesn't make sense.
- Secondly, you need to supply input to your `in0, in1, ..., in7` signals, as they seem to drive your **output** signal `R_out`, along with the other input signal `Rs`